# Jquery ajax load content twice

Tags: jquery, ajax

I wrote simple load content by AJAX in jQuery:

```
$('.bar a[rel]').live('click', function() {
    if($('.modal-'+ $(this).attr('rel')).length == 0) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'users/'+ $(this).attr('rel'),
            success: function(data) {
                $('header + .container').children().animate({
                    'height': 0,
                    'padding': 0,
                    'opacity': 0
                }, 500, function() {
                    $(this).remove();

                    $(data).hide().appendTo('header + .container').fadeIn(1000);
                });                 
            }
        });
    }

    return false;
});
```

Why this code load content (appendTo) twice?

Comment: Just FYI, `.live()` is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7 you should use `.on()`http://api.jquery.com/live/ . And `success` will be soon deprecated you should be using `.done()` instead. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: @jerome The `success` property of the parameter to the `.ajax` method is not deprecated. What is deprecated is the `jqXHR.success` method which has been replaced by `.done`, as you pointed out.

Comment: @nbrooks you are correct I misunderstood the notice, thanks.

Comment: Guys, when i use .live() or .on() always works, but the question is: why twice?

Comment: @kicaj Deprecated doesn't mean that it doesn't work, it means it is no longer supported and will disappear in updated versions. Just because it hasn't broken anything yet isn't an excuse to keep using it. It's better to make the change now rather than some months down the road when your CDN linked jQuery version is updated and your site functionality breaks. As for the question *"why twice"*, see my  answer below, let me know if it helps.

Comment: did you define your function in a separate file? I think, you may put the link twice.

Comment: @nbrooks: it's good point. I use on().

Comment: @PoyaEraghi: I use jquery-min.js (oryginal), my jquery-custom.js with this code and other functions, but problem is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The animation code is executed once for each of the children; you haven't provided your HTML, but since it runs twice, I think it's safe to assume there are two. Revise the function to work directly on the parent:

```
$('header + .container').animate({
    'height': 0,
    'padding': 0,
    'opacity': 0
}, 500, function () {
    $(this).empty();

    $(data).hide().appendTo('header + .container').fadeIn(1000);
});
```

Depending on the effect you are trying to achieve, there are other alternatives, which include queueing the animations on the children and only appending the data after all have completed. A cruder way could also be delaying the data append by at least the multiple of the length of children with the animation time (500ms in this case). It really all depends on what you want it to look like, but somehow I expect the simple approach will be fine.

P.S. You're selector looks strange, but since you got the append working at all I suspect that's just an abbreviated form for the purpose of this forum or a typo. Otherwise something's definitely wrong.

Comment: This works with one change: `$('header + .container').children().animate(...` it's must be, because I want animate and remove (by `empty()`) childrens and add data to `$('header + .container')`. Now works perfectly, thanks!

Comment: @kicaj Sure glad to help. If your problem is resolved, please mark the answer as accepted by clicking the check mark on the left to [change it green](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/205949).